# How to reproduce these sounds (Rick and Morty, and Castlevania)

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, midi, plugins

I'm absolutely new to this field. 
I'm building a laser harp, and I'm choosing the sound that the midi output will have.

There are two sounds I'd absolutely like to reproduce in a software like FL studio or audacity.

The first is [this one](https://youtu.be/E6TUs69Cw94?t=8), from the intro of Rick and Morty, at second 9. 
The [second one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUkuxAfC328), that I guess is much easier, is from a video game I used to play ages ago. I'm interested in the effect of the guitar at the opening.

Finding plugins/effects that would produce similar sounds would be ideal, and any help would be greatly appreciated. If I have to deal with spectral properties of the signal somehow I have the theoretical knowledge, as I'm actually doing research in Brain-Computer Interfaces.  I've never applied signal processing to sounds though, so I would not know at first which tools I'd require in practice. But anyway I'm hoping that there's a plugin that would do the job :)

Comment: Best place to start is download a couple free VST synths and play around with them. If that's not enough, buy a more serious virtual instrument and play around with that.

Answer (score 1):

Rick and Mo..BURRAP..orty forever! Woo Yeah.

Anyhoo, both sounds are quite simple and commonly used, but I'm not going to give you an in-depth run-through because for a start, it doesn't seem like you would know what the hell I was talking about. So, I'll give you some info and then it's up to you to LEARN!

For the Rick and Morty one, I would start with a noise sweep using a band pass or low pass filter, then add some fast, low feedback stereo delay and possibly a phaser/flanger for thickening.
I did this very quickly(5 mins) in a synth I built in Reaktor:

For the second one, an effect is added to a guitar thing, I think it's when they run their fingers down the frets, don't know what it's called, but the effect is more important here. It's a Flanger/Phaser effect. Popularly used in guitar effect pedals. To get the best result, you should learn about these effects before you use them so you understand what each knob does and how it does it.
Here is a quick example of a flanger at work over a quick bassline I created in my synth(it is the phasing effect):

And a Phaser effect from one of my projects:

Any free plugins should be fine, a flanger or phaser, a stereo delay and a filter, if needed, but you could most likely use the instruments and effects included in FL Studio. I'm sure there's a noise generator. I've never used it, so I couldn't tell you for sure.

By the way, I don't get this bit *"I'm choosing the sound that the MIDI output will have"*; midi outputs just output MIDI data, not sound. The MIDI data triggers sounds in other devices.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples sound like the pitch lowers from start (attack) to the end (release). The second one actually resembles a guitar slide.

Since you already have an instrument that tracks midi (the laser harp) you might want to go for tracking some CC values instead of notes and assign those to various parameters of an synth - pitch would be first, for this type of sound.

Here is an example of something similar sounding outputted from a popular vst synth

Answer (score 0):

the first one has a hint of [TB303](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbZeZzwQwpA) and the second one is just a GUITAR that has a heavy use of [flanger and chorus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tshpPmS40oY) effects with automation on the mix parameter ...